# What is the most efficient way to setup multiple popups using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure something out and I'm not sure how to properly setup multiple popups using javascript. This is really my first time using javascript on a website, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

So on the site, I've got a bunch of buttons which should each link to a specific popup. The first button works great, as the popup appears and the content within it shows up and works (it's dropdown I had setup).

Now, how would I setup the other buttons for their own popups? Do I need to create a new javascript file for each button and reference accordingly as I clone the HTML? Same with the CSS? How would this be setup properly?

```js
;
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("learn-more-popup");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-coach");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

      
      
        
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#learn-more-popup {
    max-width: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #2078bc;
    font-family: Muli;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    border: 0px solid #1e2027;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #000;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.coach-photo img   {
 border: 2px solid #000080 !important;
}

/* ----- Accordian ----- */
.accordion-coach {
    background-color: #000080;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.4s;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.accordion-coach:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.accordion-coach:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
 max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

/* ----- Modal Background ----- */
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* ----- Modal Content ----- */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 30px 16px 30px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
   overflow-y: scrollbar !important;
 overflow: auto !important;
max-height: 400px !important;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  
.modal-content {
width: 90% !important;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 600px !important;
}
}

/* ----- Close Button ----- */
.close {
    color: #000000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000080;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="learn-more-popup">Learn More</button>
<div id="myModal-1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <button class="accordion-coach">About Me</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-coach">Learn More</button>
<div class="panel">
  <strong>Am I your Ideal Coach?</strong>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-coach">Schedule A Call</button>
<div class="panel">
  <strong>Schedule a 15-minute consultation:</strong>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-coach">Hire This Coach</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>#</p>
</div>
  </div>

</div>
 <script src="/public_html/wp-content/themes/bridge-child/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can write your code in for loop where you are getting all the elements by class name.

Comment: @Narendra Can you please explain this a bit more on what you mean? I'm trying to figure out how I can get this working with multiple popups.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways you can approach this. The quickest and dirtiest might be to just copy the popups for each instance and code them like what you have. However, this is very dirty and not reusable.

A slightly better way would be to do a simple template of the popup html and put it inside a js function. Then you could render a new popup instance each time a button is clicked. Something like:

```
function myPopup (bodyText) {
  //create popup html content
  //append new popup html to the body
}

var somePopup = new myPopup('something');
```

While this is a generic way to do things, it gets in the mindset of building components, which is what all major frameworks are trying to achieve in the best way possible. Once you have a basic function with the minimum of what you need, you could try adding internal methods, like a remove method, update method, etc to make it more robust.

It would also be beneficial to search for tutorials on vanilla javascript components and html templates to see different ideas and patterns.